# How to set the TMOUT in Putty

Tags: ssh, putty

I'm working in Linux.  My connection to PuTTY times out very quickly and I need to have it remain active as long as I wish.  I set the `TMOUT` in my Linux `.profile` but that has not seemed to make any difference.

How do I set `TMOUT` or whatever for PuTTY?

Comment: have you tried [tcp keepalives](http://tartarus.org/~simon/putty-snapshots/htmldoc/Chapter4.html#config-tcp-keepalives)?

Comment: thanks anthon for a  very clear and comprehensive answer.  Appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the keep alive settings within PuTTY to keep your session active.

[image: ss of putty config]

There are 2 types of keepalives that you can configure. The [1st type](http://tartarus.org/~simon/putty-snapshots/htmldoc/Chapter4.html#config-keepalive) will keep the connection alive, by simulating fake activity within the SSH session. These types of disconnections are done by the remote server when it perceives inactivity.

The [2nd type](http://tartarus.org/~simon/putty-snapshots/htmldoc/Chapter4.html#config-tcp-keepalives) is due to a firewall that may be in between you and your remote SSH server. Again the firewall server perceives inactivity and drops your connection at the TCP level.

You'll have to determine which method is leading to your connection being dropped and then configure for it accordingly in the PuTTY configuration dialog.

#### References

- [4.13.1 Using keepalives to prevent disconnection](http://tartarus.org/~simon/putty-snapshots/htmldoc/Chapter4.html#config-keepalive)
- [4.13.3 Enable TCP keepalives](http://tartarus.org/~simon/putty-snapshots/htmldoc/Chapter4.html#config-tcp-keepalives)