# Where is TMOUT being set in CentOS 7? How can I disable it?

Tags: bash, timeout, logout

I know I've tracked this down before but can't find the answer.

When I start a bash shell on CentOS 7 (from X Windows GNOME or KDE), the variable `TMOUT` is set which causes the shell to timeout after the specified period of inactivity.

The variable is readonly so I can't unset it or change it!

```
unset TMOUT
# prints bash: unset: TMOUT: cannot unset: readonly variable
export TMOUT=99999
# prints bash: TMOUT: readonly variable
```

Normally `/etc/bashrc` sets these kinds of things.  I've tried to find where it is set using:

```
grep TMOUT $HOME/.??* /etc/* 2> /dev/null
# not found
```

So I don't think the `TMOUT` is actually being set in `/etc/bashrc` or if it is not being set in the way I was looking for it.

Other questions have been asked but they are not the same or not helpful.

- [read-only-tmout-variable-workaround](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/222283/read-only-tmout-variable-workaround-to-disable-automatically-exit-shell-when-t)
- [how-to-set-the-tmout-in-putty](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/98835/how-to-set-the-tmout-in-putty)
- [workaround-for-too-short-auto-logout, on superuser.com](https://superuser.com/questions/1212155/workaround-for-too-short-auto-logout/1212452)

Comment: Look at in `/etc/profile` or `/etc/profile.d/`.

Comment: @lpor Sicer, Thanks.  It was in /etc/profile.d/local.sh.  I would mark this comment as the answer if I could!

Comment: In my case, it was `/etc/environment`.

Comment: @MateenUlhaq, what Unix distribution & version set `TMOUT`  in `/etc/environment`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To disable the time out I changed the file /etc/profile.d/local.sh.
I commented out lines that were setting the timeout variable and making it readonly.

```
vi /etc/profile.d/local.sh
#export TMOUT=43200
#readonly TMOUT
```

An alternative would be to set TMOUT=0 which means to disable the timeout.  Man page for bash TMOUT is http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html.

The most important change is to comment out the line that made the variable "readonly".  If the variable could be changed, then I could have modified it in my own login settings (e.g., $HOME/.bashrc, or .bash_profile).

Comment: Typically, for compliance reasons, the config should remain set.  That said, Is there a way to effectively override this config value which makes the environment variable read only, temporarily?  The idea here being that at the discretion of a systems administrator, the value could be unset for a particular session, but still enabled by default for all others.

Comment: @ChrisSmith, From my experimentation, once the variable is set to readonly, it can not be changed.  What could be done is to have something that uses ```whoami``` or ```id -u``` to get a users name or UID and have the script skip the setting for a specific user.